# How to use React Router with d3.js Graphs to redirect to another screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, redux, react-router

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";
import ApiHelper from "../../api/ApiHelper";
import { scaleLinear } from "d3-scale";
import { max } from "d3-array";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import "../../css/styles.css";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

class JarvisDonutChart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      uid: props.uid,
      width: props.width,
      height: props.height,
      title: props.title,
      colorscheme: props.colorscheme,
      Dates: props.CalendarDates,
      fromDate: props.CalendarDates.fromDate,
      toDate: props.CalendarDates.toDate,
      graphTitle: props.graphTitle,
      chartData: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getChartData();
  }

  getChartData = () => {
    ApiHelper.GetDonutChartData(
      this.state.uid,
      this.state.fromDate,
      this.state.toDate
    )
      .then(response => {
        console.log(
          "<--- Request is successfull and below is the response -->"
        );
        console.log(response.data.responses);
        const res = response.data.responses;
        this.setState({ chartData: res }, this.drawChart);
        // setloading(false);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ chartData: [] });
        switch (error.response.status) {
          case 403:
            console.log("Error code --> " + 403);
            this.props.history.push("/unAuthorizedPage");
            break;
          default:
            console.log("Error String --->" + error);
        }
      });
  };

  drawChart() {
    const data = this.state.chartData;
    // const data = ApiHelper.GetDonutChartData(
    //   "abeab3cb-778e-4a19-a957-43bc74248b04179"
    // );
    const colorscheme = this.state.colorscheme;
    console.log("Inside Donut Chart Component");
    console.log(data);

    var width = this.state.width;
    var height = this.state.height;
    var margin = Math.min(this.state.width, this.state.height) * 0.01;

    // The radius of the pieplot is half the width or half the height (smallest one). I subtract a bit of margin.
    var radius = Math.min(this.state.width, this.state.height) / 2 - margin;

    // append the svg object to the div called 'my_dataviz'
    const svg = d3
      // .select("#abeab3cb-778e-4a19-a957-43bc74248b04")
      .select("[uid=" + this.state.uid + "]")
      .attr("width", this.state.width)
      .attr("height", this.state.height)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    // Compute the position of each group on the pie:
    var pie = d3.pie().value(function(d) {
      //console.log(d.value.value);
      //d.value.(responsefield)
      return d.value.value;
    });
    var data_ready = pie(d3.entries(data));

    console.log("<-- Checking data-ready  --> ");
    console.log(data_ready);

    // Define the div for the tooltip
    var div = d3
      .select("#" + this.props.uid + "_tooltip")
      // .append("div")
      // .attr("id", "jarvis_tooltip")
      // .attr("class", "tooltip")
      .attr("rx", 3)
      .attr("ry", 3);

    // console.log(data_ready);
    // console.log(colorscheme);

    // Build the pie chart: Basically, each part of the pie is a path that we build using the arc function.
    svg
      .selectAll("whatever")
      .data(data_ready)
      .enter()
      .append("a")
      .attr(
        "href",
        (d, i) =>
          `/drilldown-page/${this.state.title}/${this.state.graphTitle}/${data_ready[i].data.value.name}`
      )
      .append("path")
      .attr(
        "d",
        d3
          .arc()
          .innerRadius(radius * 0.45) // This is the size of the donut hole
          .outerRadius(radius)
          .cornerRadius(radius * 0.03) // sets how rounded the corners are on each slice
          .padAngle(radius * 0.0001) // effectively dictates the gap between slices
      )
      .attr("fill", (d, i) => this.state.colorscheme[i])

      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-width", "0.7px")
      .style("opacity", 0.9)
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        d3.select(this)
          .attr("stroke", "white")
          .attr("stroke-width", 1.5);
        d3.select(this).style("cursor", "pointer");
        div.style("display", "inline");

        // console.log("mouseover event triggered");
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d, i) {
        d3.select(this)
          .attr("fill", colorscheme[i])
          .attr("stroke", "black")
          .attr("stroke-width", 0.5);
        d3.select(this).style("cursor", "default");
        div.style("display", "none");
        // console.log("mouseout event triggered");
      })
      .on("mousemove", function(d) {
        div
          .text(d.value)
          .style("left", d3.mouse(d3.select("body").node())[0] + 15 + "px")
          .style("top", d3.mouse(d3.select("body").node())[1] + 20 + "px");
        // console.log("mouseover event triggered");
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <svg
          uid={this.props.uid}
          width={this.state.width}
          height={this.state.height}
        />
        <div id={this.props.uid + "_tooltip"} className="jarvis_tooltip" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    CalendarDates: state.calendarDates,
    fromDate: state.calendarDates.fromDate,
    toDate: state.calendarDates.toDate
  };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(JarvisDonutChart);
```

I am using d3.js to build interactive graphs in our application, and the user requirement is that, if user clicks on the bar or donut chart then it should take him to another screen with details related to that set of data only.

[First Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eINr4.png)

[After clicking on the graph, it leads to this screen(Second Screen)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ho4eI.png)

In d3.js I am using below code

.attr(
        "xlink:href",
        (d, i) =>
          `/drilldown-page/${this.state.title}/${this.state.graphTitle}/${data_ready[i].data.value.name}`
      )

The Problem I have facing right now is , since it href the page gets refreshed and the entire redux store gets booted again, so all the data in store like calendar dates are gone.

SO how can i use react-router with this any idea???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by myself and the solution I have implemented is below.

D3.js provides the event handler method i.e selection.on().
so attach an event handler for click on the graph element and call a function inside the callback function.

And the in the new function use history.push to redirect to the different URL.

Code is attached

```js
.on("click", function(d) {
        console.log("<--- Inside Event generator --->");
        console.log(d);
        clickHandler(d);
      });
    const clickHandler = d => {
      console.log("<-- Inside Event Handler function --->");
      console.log(d.name);
      this.props.history.push(
        `/drilldown-page/${this.state.title}/${this.state.graphTitle}/${d.name}`
      );
    };
```

Hope my answer benefits someone , who is using React and d3.js and stuck with redirection.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your code but you can add **onClick** props on some wrapper/container of graph with method like this

```js
// At the top
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

// In wrapper component
const history = useHistory();
const redirect = () => {
   history.push(`/drilldown-page/${this.state.title}/${this.state.graphTitle}/${data_ready[i].data.value.name}`);
}
```

and pass that to prop **onClick={redirect}**

Comment: I have added the code, please have a look and didn't get you completely .