# d3+react.js on click of d3 tree node text this.props.history.push gives error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props')"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

With the help of d3 and react.js, I am able to create d3 hierarchy tree

[image]

What I want to achieve is, On click of each node text (eg John, Luke, ...) it should route to detail page of each clicked text.

```
nodes
    .append("text")
    .attr("font-size", "17px")
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .text(function (d) {
        return `${d.data.name}`
    })
    .on("click", function (event, d) {
        this.props.history.push(`/detail/${d.id}`);
});
```

constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props)                  // there is history in props
    this.state = {
      isClicked: ""
      };
    this.geGraph = this.getGraph.bind(this);  // function where graph code presents
```

after clicking the node text. I getting error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'history')
```

Also when I debug on line `this.props.history.push`, there is no `props` in `this` .

Tried to follow this [How to use React Router with d3.js Graphs to redirect to another screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60996510/how-to-use-react-router-with-d3-js-graphs-to-redirect-to-another-screen) . still got the same issue. and when i try to go for arrow function

```
.on("click", (event, d) => this.props.history.push(`/detail/${d.id}`))
```

it gives issue for props this time `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props')`

I have added history in  `<Route history={createBrowserHistory()}/>` as well `import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";`. and did `export default withRouter(MyGraph)` imported from `import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';`.

***I m using router version `"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1"` and class based components with typescript.***

How do I resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your are using this on **different scope**, its scope is functional now, its better to define a function for click inside component and call it on click event.

Or you can store **this** value in another variable inside nodes creation scope and use it from that.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Are you asking me to try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60996510/how-to-use-react-router-with-d3-js-graphs-to-redirect-to-another-screen .I tried it but didn't work. If not, can you please help me with some snippet or something like that.

Comment: can you share the snippet how to define the callback

Comment: this the one i tried

`.on("click", function(event, d) {
        clickHandler(d);
      });

const clickHandler = (event, d) => {
  this.props.history.push(
    "/detail/ " + d.id
  );
};`

Answer (score 0):

According to the javascript DOM API [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_value_of_this_within_the_handler), the reference to `this` will be the DOM element you will click on.

```js
nodes
    .append("text")
    .attr("font-size", "17px")
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .text(function (d) {
        return `${d.data.name}`
    })
    .on("click", function (event, d) {
        // try console.log here
        console.log(this);   // <--- most likely be a DOM element you clicked
        this.props.history.push(`/detail/${d.id}`); // <--- therefore this.props does not exist
});
```

### Solution 1

use either Javascript [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
.on("click", (event, d) => {
        console.log(this);   // <--- this should refer to the parent object
        this.props.history.push(`/detail/${d.id}`);
});
```

### Solution 2

or bind the click event handler in the constructor with `this`

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props)                  
    this.state = {
      isClicked: ""
      };
    this.geGraph = this.getGraph.bind(this);
    this.nodeClickHandler = this.nodeClickHandler.bind(this);
}

function nodeClickHandler (event, d) {
    this.props.history.push(`/detail/${d.id}`);
}
```

```js
nodes
    .append("text")
    .attr("font-size", "17px")
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .text(function (d) {
        return `${d.data.name}`
    })
    .on("click", this.nodeClickHandler);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. tried with first solution gave same issue. tried solution it is saying `Property 'history' does not exist on type`. can you please let me know why is this happening?

Comment: what did you get in the console.log ? is it the props of the component or is it some other object? if its your component's props, did you wrap your component with withRouter higher order component?
https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter

Comment: Best would be if you can recreate your component example using codesandbox and share it. it will be easier to debug
https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: ya i have wrapped it with withRouter. console.log says has object without props, will try to recreate it in codesandox